# Handling Multiple OAuth2 Tokens

Tags: php, gmail, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I'm curious about using two APIs that both utilize OAuth2 authentication in the same application.  A simple webpage as an example would work just fine in this case.

I tried to find resources to explain the use of the OAuth2 tokens and how they relate to the session.  Do you have multiple tokens for multiple APIs?  Can you modify a token in session so that it relates to multiple APIs?  Even if you can do that, is it a good practice to do so?

I've looked at a couple of OAuth2 implementations with [PHP](http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/) and the GMail example, but haven't found anything to explain it as well as I'd like.

Any information or links to information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Upon reviewing some more literature on the subject, I believe this may just be a matter of storing multiple tokens associated with a user in a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options: the first is to request authorization for each API (say Drive and G+, etc), but the second option is to enhance the scope of your first request to include both.

In the G+ Platform docs, step 2 of Basic Steps explains that you are allowed to use multiple scopes in a request: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Ideally, your user will only need to grant access one time for everything you need.

Comment: I should have been more specific in my description.  It's not an issue of two Google applications, but rather a Google application and one from a different company, say Facebook for example.  In this manner, there is both a token from Google and a token from Facebook.

Comment: You will need a token for each application---and you'll need to follow each protocol exactly.  There won't be a shortcut.  So, I believe you'll just be holding multiple tokens at once, but implementing each protocol sequentially or so.